# Как сделать проверку в js

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно, чтобы если пользователь ввел число, вывело ошибку. Знаю, что prompt приводит любые значения к строке, но не знаю как сделать саму проверку, ведь все мне вернется строкой...

```
let itemIncome = prompt("какой у вас дополнительный заработок?", 
            "преподаю");
            console.log(itemIncome)
            if(typeof itemIncome !== ''){
                console.log("ошибка");
            };
```

Comment: `if (!isNaN(itemIncome))` ?

Comment: спасибо! Буду дальше думать, забыл совсем про isNaN

Comment: а если символ вводится? ,; и тд

Comment: ну тогда регулярка на число в помощь))

Comment: Если отменят prompt, прилетит null... могут ввести строку из одних пробелов. А профессия также может состоять и из тире / пробелов. Тут надо определиться, какие выражения должны пройти проверку и проверить введенную строку на это, а не пытаться отсеить всё остальное. Да, нужны регулярные выражения...

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы выдавало ошибку при вводе чисел или отмене запроса или при вводе только пробелов можно написать так:

```
if(!itemIncome || !itemIncome.trim() || /\d/.test(itemIncome) ){
    console.log("ошибка");
};
```

Comment: Так на любую цифру в строке выведется.

Comment: ок, вопрос был задан: "Мне нужно, чтобы если пользователь ввел число, вывело ошибку."

Comment: `qqq1www` - это число?